# Adding Space Between HStack and VStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, text, modifier

I am new to swift UI . I am trying to create simple login form in swift ui . I am trying to put round shape at top let corner and with in that I also put and text filed. Then I trying to put image within VStack with respective text and button but the design is expending through the bottom and I am trying to increase the width of the Login button but actually it not increasing ..

Here is the my code ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Color.clear
            HStack() {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 60)

                Text("SLOP")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)

            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image("login")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()

            Text("Hello !")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
            Text("Please select the Option")
                .bold()
            Button {
                print("Login button was tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Login")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 1000, height: 60)
            }

            Button {
                print("Registration button was tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Registration")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 60)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of actual design .
[image: UI Design]

Here is the screenshot of the app.  The image is not correct position and login text button width not increased .

[image: Screenshot when I run the app]

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: yes . Let me add the screenshot

Comment: The design screenshot is added . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an `.overlay` for the circle and text in the top-left corner. To make sure the overlay is really positioned in the top-left corner of the screen, set `maxHeight: .infinity` on the `VStack`. You might want some extra padding in places too.

For the login button, just set `maxWidth: .infinity` and apply the background color *after* this (the order of the modifiers is important).

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image("login")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()

            Text("Hello !")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
            Text("Please select the Option")
                .bold()
            Button {
                print("Login button was tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Login")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.blue) // after setting the max width
            }

            Button {
                print("Registration button was tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Registration")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 60)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 60)

                Text("SLOP")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)

            }
            .padding(.leading, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why use an overlay here? Nothing is being overlaid. Could just be a VStack with everything in it.

Comment: @Fogmeister The overlay works for all screen sizes (including tiny ones in landscape mode) and also ensures that the main content is centered vertically when there is excess vertical space..

Comment: Ah yeah. I didn’t realise it wanted to be centred vertically. 